# How to await a callback function call in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I am new to Node.js and Javascript, I used [npm package retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry) to send requests to server.

```
const retry = require('retry');

async function HandleReq() {

//Some code
return await SendReqToServer();
}

async function SendReqToServer() {
 
operation.attempt(async (currentAttempt) =>{
        try {
            let resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/", data, options);
            return resp.data;
        } catch (e) {
            if(operation.retry(e)) {throw e;}
        }
    });
}
```

I get empty response because `SendReqToServer` returns a promise before function passed to `operation.attempt` resolves the promise.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: `SendReqToServer` doesn't return anything, is this on purpose?

Comment: `return resp.data` returns data to the `.attempt` callback. You'll want to return `operation.attempt(...)` to return the value to `SendReqToServer`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox `SendReqToServer` returns a promise.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, but it resolves immediately after calling `operation.attempt()` - without actually waiting for anything - since there's basically an implicit `return undefined;` at the end of the function.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes indeed. - OP: `SendReqToServer` resolves to `undefined`, I assume this is not on purpose

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen This sentence _"`SendReqToServer` doesn't return anything,"_ is wrong. That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, but that's just irrelevant semantics. For the context of the question, it basically doesn't return anything.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen It's a big difference. Programming is a very exact field. You shouldn't write wrong things just because it's not relevant in this context. Saying that an async function doesn't return anything is simply wrong.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it doesn't return anything, but it doesn't matter in this context, as the HandleRequest returns the promise before server could respond. And if my understanding is right, it happens because, the callback function passed waits for axios's promise to resolve, but operation.attempt doesn't, is my understanding right ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik No need to lecture me about what programming is or isn't. And his comment still isn't wrong from this particular perspective. When using an abstraction like the async/await keywords, for all intents and purposes, the function doesn't return anything. The whole point of an abstraction like this, is to be able to ignore verbosity such as promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this question depends on `operation.attempt`. If it returns a promise you can simply return that promise in `SendReqToServer`, too. But usually async functions with callbacks don't return promises. Create your own promise:

```
const retry = require('retry');

async function HandleReq() {

//Some code
return await SendReqToServer();
}

async function SendReqToServer() {
 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        operation.attempt(async (currentAttempt) => {
            try {
                let resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/", data, options);
                resolve(resp.data);
                return resp.data;
            } catch (e) {
                if(operation.retry(e)) {throw e;}
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works, but the above mentioned issue happens because the callback function passed waits for `axios's` promise to resolve, but `operation.attempt's` doesn't, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish That's correct. `operation.attempt` is called and it almost immediately finishes. The callback runs asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, but you said if `operation.attempt` returns a promise, we can return it as such, but how can we be sure that that promise will contain the value returned in it's callback's promise ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish You have to read documentation or source code to be see what it actually returns.

Comment: oh ok, got it, thanks, but it need not be always the case right, even if `operation.attempt` returns a promise ?

Comment: You have to return a promise to await a function. You can either create your own promise or return an existing promise.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `operation.attempt()` will return `resp.data` **if there were no errors in the function** to `sendReqToServer()`.
Currently, you're just returning the `resp.data` to `operation.attempt()`. You need to also return `operation.attempt()`

```
const retry = require('retry');

async function HandleReq() {

//Some code
return SendReqToServer();
}

async function SendReqToServer() {
 
return operation.attempt(async (currentAttempt) => {
        try {
            let resp = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/", data, options);
            return resp.data;
        } catch (e) {
            if(operation.retry(e)) {throw e;}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What if `operation.attempt` doesn't return a promise? This won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. `operation.attempt` doesn't return a promise